# Probability Notation "Hierarchy"

Tags: probability

I was wondering if there's any "hierarchy" in probability notation, such as the basic "multiplication comes before summation" so that if you have: A * B + C you know that this means (A * B) + C and not A * (B + C).

So, in the case of probability, I was wondering what P(A, B | C) actually means. Does this mean the joint probability of A and B, both conditional on C? Which would be something like P((A, B) | C). Or is it the joint probability of A and B, but only B conditional on C? (if this makes any sense) Which would be something like P(A, (B | C)).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It means $P((A,B) |C)$. Note that $P( \cdot |C)$ defines a new probability measure in your sample space, and $P(A,B|C)$ means the probability of the event $A \cap B$ in this new measure.